# How View static constants are loaded in JVM unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-testing

I have a method that checks visibility is `View.GONE` or not (just for testing purpose)

```
private fun isGoneVisibility(visibility: Int): Boolean {
    return visibility == View.GONE
}
```

Then I call it in my unit test on local JVM. I thought in JVM test we don't have any Android dependency (because the JVM environment doesn't have **android.jar**). But when the test executing, it can evaluate the exact value of `View.GONE` (which is 8).

I don't have any idea about how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After build, static final primitives variables will be cover to value

[image]

Comment: How about the `static final` field that the value is unknown when the app is compiling? Like `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.